# How do I handle validation on multi tabbed html form, how do i know that there is a validation error

Tags: html

I am making use of the inbuilt validation available for input fields in Html5

So for example here I am limiting the range of numbers that can be entered

```
<input name="1_DISC_NO" id="1_DISC_NO" value="-1" style="width:100%" type="number" min="1" max="999">
```

and so if user enter invalid value they get a nice message

[image]

The trouble is this page is multi-tabbed, so if they go to another tab make some changes and click *Save*, nothing will happen because we still have error on another tab, but there is nothing to indicate that there is an error

[image]

**Is there an easy way for me to be aware that there is a validation error allowing me to display an error message at the top of the page.**

Comment: You can add your custom validation on Save event and show errors (if any) as notification on top of the page

Comment: Would this be of any help for you? https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/QBVZzx?editors=0110 I'm using my own tab system (CSS only) though

Comment: http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/examples/bootstrap-tab/

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is use the oninvalid HTML attribute. This attribute can be used to trigger a custom script when the input entered is invalid. Create a error section and populate it with message when invalidFunction is triggered and clear it if you are able to submit your form. Check out the snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 id="errorHeader"></h2>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" required oninvalid="invalidFunction(event, 'First Name is mandatory')"><br>
  <button type="submit">
  Submit
  </button>
</form>

<script>
function invalidFunction(e, message) {
e.preventDefault();
document.getElementById('errorHeader').innerText = message;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI, thankyou for pointing me towards oninvalid, this sort of works but I have a  couple of questions. Given I have 5 tabs on my page and I have an invalid value on tab1 if I go to tab2 and click on Save then invalid gets triggered and message displayed, but if i stay on tab1 (where the error is) nothing gets displayed and Save is enacted,

Comment: 2nd question. If I have two errors than two messages are displayed (im using Bootstrap alert classes). If I then click on save again I end up with two more (duplicate) messages. So I want to clear them out i tried adding an onclick event to my save button to clear any existing alert messages but his didnt work

Comment: Your error div needs to be at the parent level of the tabs so that it gets displayed. If any input element is not valid, it should not trigger form submission so its weird you are able to submit the form. Make sure all inputs belong to the same form. For your second question, just clear out the div by setting innerHTML of error div as "". You can clear it when user presses a key on input

Comment: There is only one div and that is outside the single <form element> shared by the tabs. I know how to empty the div but not when. The messages only get displayed when user presses submit button so I want them clear at his time but before the revalidation occurs if that make sense ?

Comment: You can add event listener on key press and check if target is your form input element. If it is empty the error div.

Comment: But what key press, I dont see why I would want to empty it on keypress, i want to empty it on form submit.

Comment: Again, that depends on how you want to handle it. See what best fits your application

Comment: I just want an approach that works, and Im not clear how to make anything work. The validation dont dispaly until you click on confirm button so that seems to be where you would clear them out but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how I accomplished this with a `jQuery` dependent script.
don't forget all of them must in `form` tag

```
<form>
    <ul class="errorMessages"></ul>

    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
        <textarea id="comments" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>​

<script>
    var createAllErrors = function() {
        var form = $( this ),
            errorList = $( "ul.errorMessages", form );

        var showAllErrorMessages = function() {
            errorList.empty();

            // Find all invalid fields within the form.
            var invalidFields = form.find( ":invalid" ).each( function( index, node ) {

                // Find the field's corresponding label
                var label = $( "label[for=" + node.id + "] "),
                    // Opera incorrectly does not fill the validationMessage property.
                    message = node.validationMessage || 'Invalid value.';

                errorList
                    .show()
                    .append( "<li><span>" + label.html() + "</span> " + message + "</li>" );
            });
        };

        // Support Safari
        form.on( "submit", function( event ) {
            if ( this.checkValidity && !this.checkValidity() ) {
                $( this ).find( ":invalid" ).first().focus();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        $( "input[type=submit], button:not([type=button])", form )
            .on( "click", showAllErrorMessages);

        $( "input", form ).on( "keypress", function( event ) {
            var type = $( this ).attr( "type" );
            if ( /date|email|month|number|search|tel|text|time|url|week/.test ( type )
              && event.keyCode == 13 ) {
                showAllErrorMessages();
            }
        });
    };

    $( "form" ).each( createAllErrors );
</script>
```

i hope that help you

Answer (score 0):

Refer following snippet:

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Tab Validation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .tab {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .tab button {
        background-color: inherit;
        float: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .tab button:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .tab button.active {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    .tabcontent {
        display: none;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ErrorList').html('');
        $('#Notifications').css('display', 'none');
        $('#CloseNotification').click(function () {
            $('#Notifications').fadeOut();
        });
    });

    function setErrors(errors) {
        var errorList = '';
        for (i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            errorList += '<li>' + errors[i] + '</li>'
        }
        if (errorList) {
            $('#Notifications').fadeIn();
            $('#ErrorList').html(errorList);
        }
    }

    function ValidateData() {
        var Errors = [];
        if ($('#firstName').val() == '')
            Errors.push('First Name is required.');
        if ($('#primaryEmail').val() == '')
            Errors.push('Primary Email is required.');
        setErrors(Errors);
    }

    function openTab(evt, tabName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Notifications" class="alert alert-danger">
    <a id="CloseNotification" href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    <div id="ErrorList">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Basic Information')">Basic Information</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Professional Information')">Professional Information</button>
</div>
<div id="Basic Information" class="tabcontent active" style="display:block;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Professional Information" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Primary Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="primaryEmail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Alternate Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="alternateEmail">
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="ValidateData()">Validate and Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

In ValidateData(), you can put your custom validation and using setErrors() you can set the errors.

Comment: hi, thanks but in your solution I have to write all the validation checks, Im using input html input validation checks just cant see way so all displayed on whatever tab is displayed.